# writing xml data to oracle database

Tags: php, xml, oracle, internationalization

I have created a php script to read data from xml and write it to oracle database
the xml data has html tags. which are in various language like English,Russian,Italian,German.

In php I am reading data from xml as

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file($file);
foreach($xml as $value)
{
       $text='';
    if($value->englishtext=='')
    {
        $text=htmlentities(str_replace("'", "&#039;", $value->translatedtext), ENT_HTML5);  
    }
    else
    {
        $text=htmlentities(str_replace("'", "&#039;", $value->englishtext), ENT_HTML5); 
    }
}
```

the insert query is
INSERT INTO Internationalization VALUES (seq_id.nextval,$text)

```
$stid2 = oci_parse(
    $conn, 
    "INSERT INTO UILABELINT VALUES (seq_uilabelint_id.nextval,'".$localeid."','".$filename."','".$value['ID']."',$t‌​ext)"
);
```

My real problem is some times the data is inserted correctly,and some times the html tags are not correctly encoded.

Can any body suggest me

1. weather i should use htmlentities() or not.
2. What i should do to display these html tags in html5.

Example of xml data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Resources>
<Section ID="AddListing">
        <englishtext><![CDATA[Add Listing]]></englishtext>
        <translatedtext/>
</Section>
<Section ID="DirectPayment">
    <englishtext><![CDATA[Receive <b>direct payments</b> from travelers.]]</englishtext>
    <translatedtext/>
</Section>
</Resources>
```

Comment: please cite the exactly insert query u're using

Comment: $stid2 = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO UILABELINT VALUES (seq_uilabelint_id.nextval,'".$localeid."','".$filename."','".$value['ID']."',$text)");

Comment: Can you share an example of what the html tags that aren't correctly encoded looks like?

Comment: yes <a href> this is encoded to &st;a href&gt;

Comment: hmmm... `&st;` is not even a valid HTML entity. Not sure if [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) will make a difference, but have you tried?

Comment: btw, instead of using `str_replace`, you can try `htmlentities($value->translatedtext, ENT_HTML5|ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use parameterized queries in modern days' software development. That is to avoid hacking injection and errors due to special characters.

Replace the line:

```
$stid2 = oci_parse(...);
```

with the following statement preparation code:

```
$stid2 = oci_parse(
    $conn, 
    "INSERT INTO UILABELINT VALUES (".
        "seq_uilabelint_id.nextval,':localeId',':fileName',':valueId',':text'".
    ")"
);

oci_bind_by_name($stid2, ":localeId", $localeid);
oci_bind_by_name($stid2, ":fileName", $filename);
oci_bind_by_name($stid2, ":valueId",  $value["ID"]);
oci_bind_by_name($stid2, ":text",     $text);
```

and finally execute the statement, you don't need to use 'str_replace' or 'htmlentities' anymore. Just get the text directly:

```
$text = $value->translatedtext;
```

More about OCI parameterizing, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php